# Accidentally disabled my Samsung HM1200 bluetooth headset and can't enable it again

Tags: 12.10, sound, bluetooth, headset

So I was setting up my bluetooth headset to my Ubuntu 12.10 desktop just for kicks, and I made a mistake. In Sound Settings under the Output tab, I changed the "Mode:" to "off". The headset has now disappeared from the sound settings entirely, however it is still connected to bluetooth. No change even after I disconnect and reconnect the headset (forget device and set up again).

Is there maybe a config file where I can adjust a line to make it revert to default?

Similar to this, [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175933/why-did-my-bluetooth-headset-disappear-from-sound-settings-and-how-can-i-get-it), but his solution of:

```
$ pactl list cards short
0   alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1  module-alsa-card.c
1   alsa_card.pci-0000_00_14.2  module-alsa-card.c
4   bluez_card.0C_14_20_28_4E_17    module-bluetooth-device.c
```

and running the command:

```
$ pactl set-card-profile bluez_card.0C_14_20_28_4E_17 a2dp
```

gave me the result:

```
Failure: No such entity
```

Oh, and it was really loud (while it was working, which is why I was messing with the settings to begin with) even with 1% volume. Not sure if that can be easily fixed. What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a standard Bluetooth setup we can change the profile of a Bluetooth audio device from the ***Hardware*** tab in *Sound settings*:

[image]

Alternatively we can use the command line to switch profiles:

```
pactl set-card-profile <name or index of card> <profile>
```

After we had chosen the profile to *"Off"* it will not be shown in the *Output* tab as a valid audio output sink. As soon as we had enabled another profile, e.g. *"a2dp"*, or *"hsp"* it comes back as a selectable device for *Output*.

#### Troubleshooting:

If this is not the case with your headset there may be an issue with the device's firmware. You may try the following steps:

- **reset pulseaudio** with the following command:

  ```
    pulseaudio -k
  ```
- **Delete `~/.pulse`:**
  All user setting which may interfere here are stored in `~/.pulse`. It is safe to delete this directory if you had not used it for custom settings files. To be able to restore the directory use the following rather than deleting:

  ```
    mv ~/.pulse ~/.pulse.000
  ```
- **Re-pair your headset:**
  Remove your device from the list of known devices, and then pair it again as a new device.
- **Use [pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol]** rather than *Sound Settings* for adjusting sound hardware settings.

Comment: Thank you. My sound settings page did not include a "Hardware" tab. I reset pulseaudio, renamed the .pulse file, and repaired my headset. That combination, followed by a reboot, worked very well. :)